# Problematic Class

Tags: python, class

Im trying to create a class called Record, though when I try to use it, something goes wrong. Im sure im overlooking something simple. Does anyone mind taking a look?

> ```
>       class Record:
>           def __init__(self, model):
>               self.model= model
>               self.doc_date = []
>               self.doc_pn = []
>               print("Record %s has been added.\n") % self             
>           def add_doc_date(self, declaration_date):
>               self.doc_date.append(declaration_date)
>           def add_doc_pn(self, declaration_pn):
>               self.doc_pn.append(declaration_pn)
>           def __str__(self):
>               res = "Name: " + self.model + "\n"
>               res = res + "Standard Part Numbers:" + str(self.std_pn) + "\n"
>               res = res + "Declaration Part Numbers" + str(self.doc_pn) + "\n"
>               return res
> ```

Comment: Can you tell us (1) how you are trying to use the class (2) what is going wrong?

Comment: The problem is that there are some bugs

Comment: Im trying to create a class to store the following data when the data is presented: Model Number, Declaration Number, and Declaration date. 
Id like to be able to call each individual model, by their number to see what declaration number and date they contain

Comment: Python errors are excellent: the error here will tell you *exactly* what is going wrong and where it is doing so. In general, instead of saying "something is going wrong", you should post the error transcript as well as the code.

Comment: @user428370: Please **update** your question with the **exact** problem you are having.  The **exact** error message.  All the details we need so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Record:
     def __init__(self, model):
         self.model= model
         self.doc_date = []
         self.doc_pn = []
         self.std_pn = []
         print("Record %s has been added.\n") % self
     def add_doc_date(self, declaration_date):
         self.doc_date.append(declaration_date)
     def add_doc_pn(self, declaration_pn):
         self.doc_pn.append(declaration_pn)
     def __str__(self):
         res = "Name: " + self.model + "\n"
         res = res + "Doc Date:" + str(self.doc_date) + "\n"
         res = res + "Standard Part Numbers:" + str(self.std_pn) + "\n"
         res = res + "Declaration Part Numbers" + str(self.doc_pn) + "\n"
         return res

>>> t=Record("rec1")
Record Name: rec1
Doc Date:[]
Standard Part Numbers:[]
Declaration Part Numbers[]
 has been added.

>>> t.add_doc_date("2010-10-10")
>>> t.add_doc_pn("30")
>>> print t
Name: rec1
Doc Date:['2010-10-10']
Standard Part Numbers:[]
Declaration Part Numbers['30']

>>>
```

Comment: Why have you posted the same answer twice?

Comment: sorry I wanted to expand on the code with the method calls showing

Comment: You can edit your previous post by clicking the `edit` link at its bottom left.

Comment: Not only can you edit your previous answer, you can also delete your previous answer.  Since you put in a second answer, I'd suggest you remove your other answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
res = res + "Standard Part Numbers:" + str(self.std_pn) + "\n"
```

I don't see `self.std_pn` defined anywhere.